# How can I consume streamed JSON in Angular.JS?

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, stream, streaming

I have the function createDB which is bound to scope in a controller, code below:

function:

```
function createDB(resource, args, scope, database, server, script_bool) {
    // Creates a new database with the name in the database argument
    args.name = database;
    args.script = script_bool;
    scope.success = null;
    scope.loadingResponse = true;

resource('http://localhost:1000/apiv1/servers/:server/databases',
    {server: server}, {create: {method: 'POST', params: args,
    transformResponse: function(data){return data}}})
    .create(args).$promise.then(function (result) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(result))
        console.log(result);
        })
}
```

controller binding:

```
$scope.createDB = function (database){createDB($resource,
    $scope.args, $scope, database, serverTools.getName(),
    $scope.scripts);};
```

Where `$scope.args`, `serverTools.getName()`, and `$scope.scripts` are variables that are set in the HTML side of things.

Currently I'm just logging things, but in the future I'd like to be able to provide status updates on how the creation process is going. To do this, I'm streaming a series of newline separated JSON objects from the API whenever a database is created. They look like this:

```
{"progress": "1" "verbose": "Start" "success": true}\n
{"progress": "50" "verbose": "Database Created Successfully" "success": true}\n
{"progress": "100" "verbose": "CAD scripts for __test_create run successfully" "success": true}\n
{"progress": "complete" "statuses": ["progress": "50" "verbose": "Database Created Successfully" "success": true "progress": "100" "verbose": "CAD scripts for __test_create run successfully" "success": true] "verbose": "Complete" "success": true}
```

As soon as an operation is completed, the JSON is sent. The goal is to hook these into a loading bar so that the user knows how the process is going. Ideally the service would keep updating the loading bar until it received a response where "progress" is "complete", at which point it would check the overall success value and colour the loading bar accordingly.

I'm not worried about setting up the loading bar. What I'm having problems with is parsing the JSON as it comes in. `console.log(result);` only gives me the first JSON object (`{"progress": "1" "verbose": "Start" "success": true}`), while `console.log(JSON.stringify(result));` gives me a mess that I'll include at the bottom. I also don't want to wait until everything has returned, I need to begin updating the scope as soon as the first JSON object arrives.

What I would like to know is: what is the accepted best practice for receiving streamed data from a RESTful API in Angular.js, and how should I implement this? Or should I make my API functions smaller, and abandon streaming in favour of multiple HTTP requests?

Here's the `JSON.stringify(request)` results:

```
[11:46:17.812] "{"0":"{","1":"\"","2":"p","3":"r","4":"o","5":"g","6":"r","7":"e","8":"s","9":"s","10":"\"","11":":","12":" ","13":"\"","14":"1","15":"\"","16":",","17":" 
","18":"\"","19":"v","20":"e","21":"r","22":"b","23":"o","24":"s","25":"e","26":"\"","27":":","28":" 
","29":"\"","30":"S","31":"t","32":"a","33":"r","34":"t","35":"\"","36":",","37":" 
","38":"\"","39":"s","40":"u","41":"c","42":"c","43":"e","44":"s","45":"s","46":"\"","47":":","48":" 
","49":"t","50":"r","51":"u","52":"e","53":"}","54":"\n","55":"{","56":"\"","57":"p","58":"r","59":"o","60":"g","61":"r","62":"e","63":"s","64":"s","65":"\"","66":":","67":" 
","68":"\"","69":"5","70":"0","71":"\"","72":",","73":" ","74":"\"","75":"v","76":"e","77":"r","78":"b","79":"o","80":"s","81":"e","82":"\"","83":":","84":" 
","85":"\"","86":"D","87":"a","88":"t","89":"a","90":"b","91":"a","92":"s","93":"e","94":" ","95":"C","96":"r","97":"e","98":"a","99":"t","100":"e","101":"d","102":" 
","103":"S","104":"u","105":"c","106":"c","107":"e","108":"s","109":"s","110":"f","111":"u","112":"l","113":"l","114":"y","115":"\"","116":",","117":" 
","118":"\"","119":"s","120":"u","121":"c","122":"c","123":"e","124":"s","125":"s","126":"\"","127":":","128":" 
","129":"t","130":"r","131":"u","132":"e","133":"}","134":"\n","135":"{","136":"\"","137":"p","138":"r","139":"o","140":"g","141":"r","142":"e","143":"s","144":"s","145":"\"","146":":"
,"147":" ","148":"\"","149":"1","150":"0","151":"0","152":"\"","153":",","154":" 
","155":"\"","156":"v","157":"e","158":"r","159":"b","160":"o","161":"s","162":"e","163":"\"","164":":","165":" ","166":"\"","167":"C","168":"A","169":"D","170":" 
","171":"s","172":"c","173":"r","174":"i","175":"p","176":"t","177":"s","178":" ","179":"f","180":"o","181":"r","182":" 
","183":"_","184":"_","185":"t","186":"e","187":"s","188":"t","189":"_","190":"c","191":"r","192":"e","193":"a","194":"t","195":"e","196":" ","197":"r","198":"u","199":"n","200":" 
","201":"s","202":"u","203":"c","204":"c","205":"e","206":"s","207":"s","208":"f","209":"u","210":"l","211":"l","212":"y","213":"\"","214":",","215":" 
","216":"\"","217":"s","218":"u","219":"c","220":"c","221":"e","222":"s","223":"s","224":"\"","225":":","226":" 
","227":"t","228":"r","229":"u","230":"e","231":"}","232":"\n","233":"{","234":"\"","235":"p","236":"r","237":"o","238":"g","239":"r","240":"e","241":"s","242":"s","243":"\"","244":":"
,"245":" ","246":"\"","247":"c","248":"o","249":"m","250":"p","251":"l","252":"e","253":"t","254":"e","255":"\"","256":",","257":" 
","258":"\"","259":"s","260":"t","261":"a","262":"t","263":"u","264":"s","265":"e","266":"s","267":"\"","268":":","269":" 
","270":"[","271":"{","272":"\"","273":"p","274":"r","275":"o","276":"g","277":"r","278":"e","279":"s","280":"s","281":"\"","282":":","283":" 
","284":"\"","285":"5","286":"0","287":"\"","288":",","289":" ","290":"\"","291":"v","292":"e","293":"r","294":"b","295":"o","296":"s","297":"e","298":"\"","299":":","300":" 
","301":"\"","302":"D","303":"a","304":"t","305":"a","306":"b","307":"a","308":"s","309":"e","310":" ","311":"C","312":"r","313":"e","314":"a","315":"t","316":"e","317":"d","318":" 
","319":"S","320":"u","321":"c","322":"c","323":"e","324":"s","325":"s","326":"f","327":"u","328":"l","329":"l","330":"y","331":"\"","332":",","333":" 
","334":"\"","335":"s","336":"u","337":"c","338":"c","339":"e","340":"s","341":"s","342":"\"","343":":","344":" ","345":"t","346":"r","347":"u","348":"e","349":"}","350":",","351":" 
","352":"{","353":"\"","354":"p","355":"r","356":"o","357":"g","358":"r","359":"e","360":"s","361":"s","362":"\"","363":":","364":" 
","365":"\"","366":"1","367":"0","368":"0","369":"\"","370":",","371":" 
","372":"\"","373":"v","374":"e","375":"r","376":"b","377":"o","378":"s","379":"e","380":"\"","381":":","382":" ","383":"\"","384":"C","385":"A","386":"D","387":" 
","388":"s","389":"c","390":"r","391":"i","392":"p","393":"t","394":"s","395":" ","396":"f","397":"o","398":"r","399":" 
","400":"_","401":"_","402":"t","403":"e","404":"s","405":"t","406":"_","407":"c","408":"r","409":"e","410":"a","411":"t","412":"e","413":" ","414":"r","415":"u","416":"n","417":" 
","418":"s","419":"u","420":"c","421":"c","422":"e","423":"s","424":"s","425":"f","426":"u","427":"l","428":"l","429":"y","430":"\"","431":",","432":" 
","433":"\"","434":"s","435":"u","436":"c","437":"c","438":"e","439":"s","440":"s","441":"\"","442":":","443":" 
","444":"t","445":"r","446":"u","447":"e","448":"}","449":"]","450":",","451":" 
","452":"\"","453":"v","454":"e","455":"r","456":"b","457":"o","458":"s","459":"e","460":"\"","461":":","462":" 
","463":"\"","464":"C","465":"o","466":"m","467":"p","468":"l","469":"e","470":"t","471":"e","472":"\"","473":",","474":" 
","475":"\"","476":"s","477":"u","478":"c","479":"c","480":"e","481":"s","482":"s","483":"\"","484":":","485":" 
","486":"t","487":"r","488":"u","489":"e","490":"}","$promise":{},"$resolved":true}"
```

Comment: Personally I'd pick smaller requests but then it's no longer considered 'streaming' which I don't think you want with JSON anyways